# displaying from an array of values in cells in a workbook very slow or not working at all

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My question is about google script
displaying from an array of values in cells in a workbook very slow or not working at all.
On the other hand, if I stop my current script, the values of the array are written immediately?
It works for specific values in specific cells but, as soon as I read my table of values, in a block, to display the values in the cells nothing appears unless I interrupt my script?
Thank you in advance for your answers
Answer requested in French please
Joel

Comment: share your script/spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

`SpreadsheetApp.flush()` forces Google Apps Script to apply the changes made so far. This should be done before coping the range that is intended to hold the result of the formula otherwise it will be empty.

`Utilities.sleep(milliseconds)` is necessary (or something equivalent) to wait for the spreasheet recalculation finish before copying the range, otherwise the only value to copy might be Loading...

And it works...